# Why is the Cocoa API so verbose?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

It seems like there's a lot of redundancy in the naming of things. A very simple example:

```
+ (UIColor *)blackColor;      // 0.0 white 
+ (UIColor *)darkGrayColor;   // 0.333 white 
+ (UIColor *)lightGrayColor;  // 0.667 white
```

...which results in code like:

```
UIColor *c = [UIColor blackColor];
```

For starters, why isn't `blackColor` simply `black`? It will always be visibly obvious that it's a black *color* because objective-c is strongly typed, and thus the class name will be present. As well as the fact that here, these are static methods sent to the class.

Comment: Good point, OP, in other languages like javascript, scripting languages like html, css, and in Android's COLOR library, basic colors are just written with their basic name like "black" "red" blue"

Comment: It's a convention. Whenever possible you state the types of the return value or the arguments in the method name.

Comment: It's verbose because _explicit is better than implicit_. Also, consider other class methods there: `+[UIColor underpageBackground]` is unclear. `underpageBackgroundColor` is much better. The other simpler color names follow that pattern and tell you exactly what you're getting.

Comment: Specifically, there's nothing preventing a class-method call to UIColor from returning a UIImage (or some other class) instance for some convenient reason or another. This way, the expected object type is in the name without looking it up. Kind of like NSOutlineView containing the word "View". Sure it's verbose, but it's specific.

Comment: For sure, I'm coming from a Rails background of "convention over configuration", as well as duck typing and not being so concerned about type in general.

Comment: And why is it that for me, the most valuable questions are always the ones that are "closed"?

Comment: I would argue it's because all message names are shared across all objects.  The namespacing of message in Objective-C is not as clean as method names in C++, etc - you can send any message to any object.  The *typing* of messages, however, needs to be consistent. Thus, if you send 'black' to *any* object, regardless of what it is intended to do, it must return the same type.  Making the names longer reduces the chances of clashes with other classes.

Comment: @DigiMonk Black holes _are_ black though because the gravity is so intense, blah blah blah